# Confluent Error: set environment variable CONFLUENT_HOME

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, confluent-platform

I have installed confluent-7.0.0 on ubuntu 20.04.Followed the official documentation https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/quickstart/ce-docker-quickstart.html .
I have added the path of confluent_home as shown below in .bashrc file.:

```
export PATH=/home/abc/confluent-7.0.0/bin:$PATH 
export PATH=$PATH:$CONFLUENT_HOME/bin
```

And run the command `source  ~/.bashrc`.
Now the problem is when I have started my services first time by `confluent local services start` it has up the services of zookeeper,kafka,schema registry,kafka-rest,connect and ksql but while starting control center it has aborted the operation.
And now when I am running this command  `confluent local services start` it is giving the following error:

```
The local commands are intended for a single-node development environment only,
NOT for production usage. https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/index.html

Error: set environment variable CONFLUENT_HOME
```

Which else environment variable do I have to set and how?

Comment: You haven't actually set the `CONFLUENT_HOME` environment variable anywhere in your post, just used it to update `PATH`.

Comment: Thanks I have set the confluent_home environment variable in bashrc and now its working.

Answer (score 3):

The error says you need `CONFLUENT_HOME` variable set. You can set `PATH` after that

This is what you need

```
export CONFLUENT_HOME=/home/abc/confluent-7.0.0 
export PATH=$CONFLUENT_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: No need to save the export statements inside .bashrc?

Comment: @Guy_g23 Yes. That's what I do (well, zshrc)